# How do I access JsonElement's Item property?

Tags: c#

Given: `JsonElement someElement = root.GetProperty("Something")`

I can use `someElement.ValueKind` to confirm that `someElement` is an array. However, I can't access `someElement.Item[0]`. I receive this error:

> "JsonElement does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no
> accessible extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type
> 'JsonElement' could be found."

Here's a [DotNetFiddle as an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/35wAzw).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code. Simply remove the `Item` tag:

```
    Console.WriteLine(studentsElement.ValueKind);
    Console.WriteLine(studentsElement[1]);
    Console.WriteLine(studentsElement[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(studentsElement[0].GetProperty("Name"));
```

and this will give you:

```
Array
--------------------------
{
      "Name": "James",
      "Grade": 81.0
}
--------------------------
{
      "Name": "John",
      "Grade": 94.3
}
--------------------------
John
--------------------------
```